# Scala logging error, com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging.$init$ method not found

Tags: scala, logging, sbt, scala-logging

Hi I tried multiple combinations of including dependencies of scala logging, however I'm getting runtime error as method init not found.

For detailed code and error I'm getting, please have a look [here](https://github.com/manish-tiwari/PracticeScala/pull/2) at my Github repository.

PS: I do know there are exisiting similar threads there but all those solutions seems to be not working in my case, so had to create this seperate thread with detailed code and error message.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import is wrong. It should be

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging
```

and not

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.slf4j.LazyLogging
```

Comment: Error: 
`
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging.$init$(Lcom/typesafe/scalalogging/LazyLogging;)V
 at com.manish.practice.sbtDependencies.HelloWordlWithScalaLogging$.<init>(HelloWordlWithScalaLogging.scala:10)
 at com.manish.practice.sbtDependencies.HelloWordlWithScalaLogging$.<clinit>(HelloWordlWithScalaLogging.scala)
 at com.manish.practice.sbtDependencies.HelloWordlWithScalaLogging.main(HelloWordlWithScalaLogging.scala
`

Comment: For updated code see [here](https://github.com/manish-tiwari/PracticeScala/pull/2/commits/0ae3441fc3705b7d903de1b594d168ae8a8f8848).

Comment: @beingManish please see that now your sbt dependency definition seems wrong. It should be:

`"com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.7.2"`

However I did a small PR on your repo fixing the problem. Please see [here](https://github.com/manish-tiwari/PracticeScala/pull/3)

Comment: Hi @beingManish thanks for inviting me to this thread. Looks like your issue has been resolved. For others who need help with setting up sbt dependency for scala-logging, I provide a step-by-step tutorial at [http://allaboutscala.com](http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-1-getting-familiar-intellij-ide/getting-started-sbt-import-dependencies-build-sbt/)